# How to delete item on click in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to delete an item in React by clicking on a button. Currently my code returns `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ProductID')` and I am not sure why since I am accessing it via an id and it should work. How can I properly make my code work and delete the item on click? Here is my attempt:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Grid, GridColumn as Column } from '@progress/kendo-react-grid';
import { sampleProducts } from './sample-products';

const allInEdit = sampleProducts.map((item) =>
  Object.assign(
    {
      inEdit: true,
    },
    item
  )
);

const deleteItem = (item) => {
  let index = sampleProducts.findIndex(
    (record) => record.ProductID === item.ProductID
  );
  data.splice(index, 1);
  return sampleProducts;
};

const MyCommandCell = () => {
  return (
    <button
      className="k-button k-grid-remove-command"
      onClick={() => deleteItem()}
    >
      Remove
    </button>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(allInEdit);

  const itemChange = (e) => {
    let newData = data.map((item) => {
      if (item.ProductID === e.dataItem.ProductID) {
        item[e.field || ''] = e.value;
      }

      return item;
    });
    setData(newData);
  };

  return (
    <Grid data={data} editField="inEdit" onItemChange={itemChange}>
      <Column field="ProductID" title="Id" width="50px" editable={false} />
      <Column field="ProductName" />
      <Column field="FirstOrderedOn" editor="date" format="{0:d}" />
      <Column field="UnitsInStock" width="150px" />
      <Column field="Discontinued" width="50px" editor="boolean" />
      <Column cell={MyCommandCell} width="240px" />
    </Grid>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('my-app'));
```

Comment: The problem here is that you are expecting a product object in delete function but you ain't getting one as you have not passed it while calling deleteItem.

Comment: @MayankBansal I tried passing it as item but that returns that item is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move your `deleteItem` and `MyCommandCell` functions inside your App component in order to to use `setData.` You also need to read current row's data from `dataItem` of current row's item. That value should be passed to the `deleteItem` function as a prop

You can use this code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Grid, GridColumn as Column } from "@progress/kendo-react-grid";
import { sampleProducts } from "./sample-products";

const allInEdit = sampleProducts.map((item) =>
  Object.assign(
    {
      inEdit: true
    },
    item
  )
);

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(allInEdit);

  const deleteItem = (item) => {
    let newProducts = data.filter(
      (record) => record.ProductID !== item.ProductID
    );
    setData(newProducts);
  };

  const MyCommandCell = (item) => {
    return (
      <button
        className="k-button k-grid-remove-command"
        onClick={() => deleteItem(item.dataItem)}
      >
        Remove
      </button>
    );
  };

  const itemChange = (e) => {
    let newData = data.map((item) => {
      if (item.ProductID === e.dataItem.ProductID) {
        item[e.field || ""] = e.value;
      }

      return item;
    });
    setData(newData);
  };

  return (
    <Grid data={data} editField="inEdit" onItemChange={itemChange}>
      <Column field="ProductID" title="Id" width="50px" editable={false} />
      <Column field="ProductName" />
      <Column field="FirstOrderedOn" editor="date" format="{0:d}" />
      <Column field="UnitsInStock" width="150px" />
      <Column field="Discontinued" width="50px" editor="boolean" />
      <Column cell={MyCommandCell} width="240px" />
    </Grid>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("my-app"));
```

You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-burnell-6i59z?file=/src/index.js) for live working example.